# base 64 code not working... not showing images from database in html php mysql form

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image: 1st image shows how my scrren looks with uploaded image]

[image: image 2 shows my database looks and type]

**image 1st shows my scrren and shows my database looks**

```
     <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <br><br><br>
  select image:<input type="file" name="image" size="40" id="image">
            <br><small> must be less than 512kb </small>

  <br><br>         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">  
  </form>
```

**not getting any error.. still not working...**

```
   <?php

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
   if(getimagesize($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'])==FALSE)

   { 
     echo "<script> please insert the image </script>";
       exit();
    }

    else
     {
    $image=addslashes($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name']);
    $name=addslashes($_FILES['image'] ['name']);
    $image= file_get_contents($image);
    $image= base64_encode($image);
     saveimage($name,$image);


     }
     }

     displayimage();

       function saveimage($name,$image)
      {
        $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","work");

        $qry="insert into pics( name, image) values('$name','$image')";

       $result= mysqli_query($con,$qry);

      if($result)
    {
     echo"<br> image uploaded";
    }

   else
    {
     echo"<br> image not uploaded";
   }

    }

    function displayimage()
   {
    $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","work");

     $qry= "select* from pics";

    $result= mysqli_query($con,$qry);
```

**i thing the problem is here in this while.. but i am not sure.. **

```
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $img_type = 'png or jpg';
      echo"<img height='250' width='250' src='data:image/".$img_type.";base64', '".$row[1]."' >";
     }
    mysqli_close($con);


    }


     ?>
```

**dont know what to do.. please help me guys**

Comment: Your `src` attribute might be malformed. It looks like you've put a closing single quote after ";base64" (before the image data). What HTML does your PHP generate?

Comment: view your HTML source as an added "tool".

Comment: i didnt get you @showdev

Comment: like how man @Fred-ii-

Comment: you do have a web browser, right?

Comment: What I mean is: the "src" part of your image tag should be in quotes. But you're closing those quotes before the image data. For example, you're doing something like `<img src='data:image/png or jpg;base64', 'the image data'>`, which is not valid. Also, "png or jpg" is not a valid image type. Check out an [example of the URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples) and carefully compare it with your generated HTML.

Comment: yes @Fred-ii- .. i use chrome

Comment: ok let me check it my man

Comment: your HTML source will reveal if you have any quotes or missing quotes, besides what @showdev mentioned above and with a link to see the examples. Viewing your HTML source is part of the debugging tools, besides var_dump print_r, error reporting, mysqli_error() etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<img height='250' width='250' src='data:image/" . $img_type . ";base64," . $row[1] . "' >";
```

Try replace your code with this as suggest by @showdev